Conceptual difference between regularized and constrained optimization.
In the literature of compressed sensing, one encounters optimization problems as shown in equation (1) and (2). focusing on the conceptual differences between regularized optimization and constrained optimization approaches used to reconstruct sparse signals from non-uniformly sampled data. Specifically, I am comparing two optimization strategies:

Regularized Optimization (Equation 1):

$$
\underset{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{C}^n}{\operatorname{argmin}}\|\tilde{\boldsymbol{F}} \boldsymbol{x}-\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}\|_{\ell_2}+\lambda\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{\ell_p}
$$
represents the sparsely sampled data, $\tilde{\boldsymbol{F}}$ is a rectangular (Fourier) matrix, and $\boldsymbol{x}$ is the desired signal spectrum. The objective function minimizes a linear combination of the $\ell_2$ norm of the reconstruction error and the $\ell_p$ norm of the spectrum, with $\lambda$ acting as a regularization parameter that balances these aspects.

Constrained Optimization (Equation 2):
or

$$
\underset{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{C}^n}{\arg \min }\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{\ell_p} \text { subject to }\|\tilde{\boldsymbol{F}} \boldsymbol{x}-\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}\|_{\ell_2} \leq \epsilon .
$$
This approach prioritizes the sparsity of $\boldsymbol{x}$, subject to a constraint that the $\ell_2$ norm of the reconstruction error between the predicted and observed data does not exceed a predefined threshold $\epsilon$.
My questions are as follows:

Conceptually, what are the key differences in focus between these two approaches?

Under what conditions might a solution to Equation 1 also satisfy Equation 2, and vice versa?


Under what scenarios one might prefer one formulation over the other. Thanks.

I think that conceptually the key difference is very direct - the first formulation does not impose an explicit constraint on the maximum allowable fitting error, but the second does.
Regarding the equivalence between the two. First, we can change the objective in Equation 2 to the norm to the power p, meaning $\|x\|_{\ell_p}^p$, without changing the problem, since this is a monotone transformation. But it makes the objective strictly convex.
Lagrangian of the constrained formulation is
$$
L(x, \eta) = \|x\|_{\ell_p}^p + \eta \| F x - y\|_{\ell_2} - \eta \epsilon
$$
So given an optimal $\eta^*$ solution of the dual problem
$$
\eta^* \in \operatorname*{argmax}_{\eta \geq 0} \{  \min_x L(x, \eta) \}
$$
an optimal solution of the constraint problem is
$$
x^* = \operatorname*{argmin}_x L(x, \eta).
$$
This is equivalent to solving your Equation 1 formulation, with $\lambda = \frac{1}{\eta*}$. So for any $\epsilon$, the second formulation can be written as an equivalent first formulation with the appropriate choice of $\lambda$. Vice versa - I don't think it's trivial that for any $\lambda$ there is a corresponding $\epsilon$.
